# How do I control the minimum length of an array passed to a function using templates?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates

I would like to create a constructor for a template class that holds 3 members of type `T`, that receives an array of type `T` and assigns the first 3 values to the members.

However, I also want to make sure the array is at least 3 members long.

The constructor syntax must be as follows:

`A<T> triplet(T array[])`

How do I make sure the array has 3 or more values, without passing additional parameters?

I tried to calculate the array size in the function, but because it is passed as a parameter, the `sizeof(array)` is the `sizeof(T*)` which doesn't work.

Comment: Take it by a reference instead: `template<std::size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<(N>=3)>> A<T> triplet(const T(&array)[N])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with this function signature. You can't extract size of array after it has decayed to a pointer (and `A triplet(T array[])` is exactly the same as `A triplet(T* array)`).

You can accept the array by reference though, and that comes with length included:

```
template <std::size_t N>
A triplet(T(&array)[N])
{
    static_assert(N >= 3, "Array must have at least 3 elements");
    // ...
    return {};
}
```

Comment: The OP said they want a constructor, not a function. The OP's class is likely `A` and `triplet` is likely a variable of type `A`. They just presented the desired syntax wrong.